# ios_base::getloc should be with const or non const?

Tags: c++, std

There are two different references to this function:

one that is with declared with const [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/getloc/);

and one that is without const [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/getloc);

Which one is correct ?

Comment: [You should look through the latest standard and find out](http://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3797.pdf). I myself can't access it on a mobile.

Comment: @0x499602D2 thanks for the link , i didn't found it yet , i will look.

Comment: @Raxvan They both look correct to me :) (I fixed the cppref page) if you grep the standard for *ios.base.locales* you'll see the function signature is `locale getloc() const`

Comment: @Praetorian Someone just recently updated it.

Comment: @0x499602D2 someone should close this topic :)) , the website just got updated :), i can't close it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard says (27.5.3.3) that the definition should be:

`locale getloc() const;`

By the time i posted this, the [website](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/getloc) was updated :)